# Create xkb configuration from xmodmap

Tags: xkb, xmodmap

I have a custom `xmodmap` file I use, including useful multi-language diacriticals, english quotes, dashes &c. I want to use this map with `kmscon`, so I need to create a `xkb` configuration from it. Is there an automated method to do it? Or even a straightforward manual process, since I won't need to do this frequently?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/347382#347382?newreg=4eb097870a15490ebbe39d78412f9797

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Make your own xkb configuration file

The idea is to "read" the current keyboard config (do not call `xmodmap`), and write your own symbols file based on it. First:

`xkbcomp -xkb $DISPLAY`

This creates `server-0_0.xkb`. In this file, take the following block:

```
xkb_symbols "pc+inet(evdev)+compose(menu)+whatever(option)" {
    key <ESC> { [ Escape ] };
    ...
};
```

change the first line into:

```
default xkb_symbols "my_symbols" {
    include "pc+inet(evdev)"
    include "compose(menu)+whatever(option)"
```

(I think you can break options into as many "include" lines as you like). Change the keys you want to modify and prepend them with `override`:

```
override key <AE10>  { [ 0, parenright, degree ]};
```

Remove all unchanged keys.

### System-wide installation

Put all this into `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/my_terrific_kb`. Now users may load it with `setxkbmap my_terrific_kb` (in `.xinitrc` or `.xsessionrc`). Probably you can put `Option "XkbLayout" "my_terrific_kb"` in `xorg.conf` for a system-wide change.

### Single-user installation

Put all this into `~/anywhere/my_terrific_kb`. Find the XInput id of your keyboard with `xinput list`. Then run `xkbcomp -i <XInput_id> ~/anywhere/my_terrific_kb $DISPLAY`.

Comment: Ok, but what should I do on a system where I am not root?

Comment: Edited answer. I'm not 100% sure for the last section: I found in my archives I did use xkbcomp to apply my custom xkb config; however I dropped this method in favour of system-wide installation, I can't remember why. Maybe you need a full keyboard definition, not just overrides. Please test. Prepare command-line `setxkbmap de` in a terminal in case things go wrong (copy-paste a newline to validate the line if Return is also broken)

Comment: Thanks. Looks complicated. I will try it as soon as I find the time for this kind of experiments. Unfortunately also the single-user installation requires root or xinput already installed. I hope the XInput_id will not change from one X session to another.? If there is no easier solution xkb is a really crippled bastard and I will stay with Xmodmap.

Comment: If the file is readable, you can `grep XINPUT /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: Note that while this starts with "do not call xmodmap", if you ignore that instruction and _do_ call it with the configuration you want to import, and then continue on from there, you'll get a file which includes your previously-defined mappings, making this a handy starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The map file produced by `xkbcomp :0 custom-xkb-keymap` consists of many components that you can load by simply swapping the arguments `xkbcomp custom-xkb-keymap :0`. It shows a few warnings here, but seems to work, when I change the layout in the file.

The xkb layout is stored in the `symbols` directory, e.g. `/usr/local/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. The path may vary depending on the system. When you need the layout, you need to cut out the part looking like:

```
xkb_symbols "id+id+id(pc104)" {
    name[group1]="..."
    .
    .
    .
};
```

and store it in the `symbols` directory. Please make sure, you don't overwrite any file there! Once it is stored there (for example as `mylayout`) you can load it by typing `setxkbmap mylayout`. And this corresponds with the `xorg.conf` setting `Option "XkbLayout" "mylayout"` in the section `InputDevice` (see [man page for kbd](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/kbd.4.html) for further details).

It seems that the other parts in the `xkcomp` output correspond to the files in the other directories, so if something does not work, you will probably have to split up the `custom-xkb-keymap` into its components and copy it to the proper directories under `/usr/local/share/X11/xkb`. But this is something I have never done, yet.

**Better layouts**

Instead of using raw dumps that look like decompiled code, you can also make your own `symbols` file, which is more readable. I have got my own custom layout, which will probably not be usable for most of you, but you can still take a look at this short file that [I use for programming on German keyboards](https://github.com/nakal/xmonad-conf/blob/f25e81bf16d212b35dfe69765a135787c09c4b7b/xkb/us_alt) (just to get an idea how this can look like and what you can do with a `symbols` file).

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem. After I applied my `xmodmap` configuration, I used `xkbcomp :0 custom-xkb-keymap` do copy the current `xkb` keymap (from display `:0`) to a file named `custom-xkb-keymap`.

Comment: Once you've done that, where do you put the file so that it's loaded automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble actually installing the keyboard on GNOME (Elementary OS) following the other answers here, but eventually I figured it out.

What I recommend is:

- Follow the other answers (L. Levrel) to export your current xmodmap to create xkb file from it (e.g. you will have `terrific_kb`)
- copy/move this file under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`
- then open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rule/evdev.xml` and add following under the language you want:

```xml
<variant>
    <configItem>
        <name>terrific_kb</name>
        <description>English (US, My Terrific Keyboard)</description>
    </configItem>
</variant>
```

- then open the usual "System Settings" > "Keyboard" GNOME UI and select your keyboard.

I also put this quick tutorial under with some of my binding changes:
https://github.com/bubersson/init/tree/master/keyboard/xkb-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar problem in this thread: [Xephyr: keyboard mapping not working properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304391/xephyr-keyboard-mapping-not-working-properly)
Similar to the provided solution you can save your keyboard settings with

```
setxkbmap -display :0 -print > mykeymap
```

This file can be applied by xkbcomp on other systems:

```
xkbcomp mykeymap :0
```

This command can take place in the autostart of gnome or other DE's. I don't know if all manual changes will be taken over, but I think it's worth a try. Where to put this file to be automatically loaded without using xkbcomp, I don't know.