# Xephyr: keyboard mapping not working properly

Tags: xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xephyr

When I start `Xephyr` and `LXDE` session inside:

```
$ Xephyr :1 -screen 1920x1054 -nolisten tcp -reset -terminate
$ DISPLAY=:1 startlxde
```

some keys are not working properly, such as
<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd>. Looking with `xev`, I see very funny key names:

```
PageUp:   Hiragana
Up:       Katakana
PageDown: Control_R
Left:     Henkan_Mode
Down:     KP_Enter
Right:    Muhenkan
```

[image]

[image]

Obviously, in normal `LXDE` session (without Xephyr), everything works normally.

One thing that is relevant here:

I am not using `udev` daemon on my system. (I just needed to add `Option         "AutoAddDevices" "Off"` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to make `X` work without `udev`.

When I turn `udev` back on, the keys inside `Xephyr` work OK. But that is not a solution for me.

How can I diagnose and fix this problem (without udev) ?

Comment: +1 Had this issue several years ago; Last time I had used Xephyr, the keyboard mapping was working properly when running in VirtualBox emulator. I didn't manage to figure out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to read the keyboard configuration of :0 with setxkbmap and to set it on :1 with xkbcomp:

```
setxkbmap -display :0 -print | xkbcomp - :1
```

Comment: that works great ! You are a genius.

Answer (score 2):

An even shorter version of mviereck's suggestion:

```
xkbcomp :0 :1
```

Comment: when I do this, my whole Xephyr session crashes

Comment: Yes, mine, too. Xephyr 2:1.20.4-1 on Debian Buster. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/70653) to [a similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/70428/how-can-i-sort-out-xephyrs-keyboard-mapping/273603) on Superuser.

The solution is to start Xnest / Xephyr with `-kb`.

There's a [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19365) in relation and it still has the status "NEW". Strange, but it may apply, though 7 years old.

Take a look at the other answers in case `-kb` didn't fix it.

And see [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/209433/xephyr-keyboard-layout?noredirect=1&lq=1) to get an insight into the `-keybd` option.

Comment: the `-kb` option does not exist anymore, and the new `-keybd` does not help either, when used as `Xephyr :1 -screen 1920x1054 -keybd ephyr,,,xkbmodel=pc105,xkblayout=us,xkbrules=evdev,xkboption=ctrl:nocaps -nolisten tcp -reset -terminate`. I suspect, the problem is related to the fact, that `udev` daemon did not "set" up something that `Xephyr` needs. As I said, the keyboard works OK when I boot with `udev` enabled.

Comment: How to pass `-kb` in firejail?